# Does CSS support inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inherit CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417356/inherit-css-class)

Does CSS support inheritance ?

Assuming we have:

```
.base
{
}

.class1 :base
{
}

.class2 :base
{
}
```

How can I make `class1` and `class2` contain all styles which exist in `base`?

Comment: No, see [Inherit CSS class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417356/inherit-css-class)

Comment: Best not to confuse the meaning of the word "class" between CSS and OOP.  They're very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't support inheritance in the class sense of the word, but is based on specifity and order. If you define a common set of properties for classes class1 and class2, and then specialize as needed.

```
.class1, .class2
{
    font-size:1.1em;
}

.class1
{
    color:red;
}

.class2
{
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. What you could do is use the base class, and have another class1, and class2 with the styles you need, than add both classes to the element.
For example:

```
.base
{
color: Black;
font-size: 12pt;
}

.class1
{
font-weight: bold;
color: Blue;
}
<div class="base">This will be black, 12pt.</div>
<div class="base class1">This will be blue, 12pt, bold.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS does support inheritance. If you html tags are laid out like:

```
<div class="base">
    ...
    <div class="class1>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Class1 and Class2 will inherit whatever styles you assign to Base as long they are not explicitly overridden in your style sheet.

```
.base {
    font-size: 12pt;    // all child elements get this font size if another font-size is not specified
}
```

Check out [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) for more.

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are some tools (like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)) that you can use to "compile" CSS.  An example:

SASS:

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background: #fdd;
}
.error.intrusion {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.badError {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

, which "compiles" to:

```
.error, .badError {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background: #fdd;
}

.error.intrusion,
.badError.intrusion {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.badError {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```