# bad convention to chain class selectors through multiple levels of inheritance?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm refactoring some html pages using css inheritance; trouble occurs when extending a style that extends from another style; properties from the base style are not picked up.

```
.font-base, .font-big, .font-bigger{
    color: GREEN;
    font-size: 11pt;
    letter-spacing: 6pt;
}

.font-big {
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.font-bigger, .font-italic {
    font-size: 30pt;
}

.font-italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/VHKGL/9/)

I was expecting `font-italic` to pick up `color` and `letter-spacing` styles from `font-base`, the base selector, but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419787/791406), css inheritance is *not* OO inheritance, so I'm assuming this *is* the expected behavior?

In the above example, however, `font-italic` picks up styling from its peer selector, `font-bigger`, which helps to avoid redundant styling, but I suspect this could get ugly real quick with multiple levels of inheritance.

**Questions**
Is it bad practice to repeatedly inherit class selectors? I'm asking because I don't do much CSS, and I want to be in accordance with good conventions.

The bonus question goes back to my original problem, is there a way to inherit styling that works like OO inheritance? I'm guessing SASS and LESS fall into that category?

Comment: Do you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/VHKGL/10/

Comment: I know it works when placing `font-italic` at the base, yes, my question asks if it's possible to do that by inheriting from a higher level, and if doing so is considered good practice.

Comment: There is no such a thing in CSS, But in SASS you can try @extend to do this http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend

Answer (score 1):

`font-italic` picks up styling as follows:

```
.font-bigger, .font-italic {
    font-size: 30pt;
}
.font-italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

`.font-base, .font-big, .font-bigger{}` does not include any reference for `font-italic`, hence, `font-italic` does not pick any style of it.(color,letter-spacing)

If you want `font-italic` to pick those styles, you can write:

```
.font-base, .font-big, .font-bigger,font-italic{
    color: GREEN;
    font-size: 11pt;
    letter-spacing: 6pt;
}
```

OR:

```
<div class="font-italic font-big">font-italic-nogreen?</div>
```

However, I would suggest you following structure for efficient styling :

CSS:

```
.font-color{
    color: GREEN;
    letter-spacing: 6pt;
}
.font-base{
   font-size: 11pt;
}
.font-big {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.font-bigger{
    font-size: 30pt;
}
.font-italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="font-base font-color">font-green-11</div>
<div class="font-big font-color">font-big-14</div>
<div class="font-bigger font-color">font-bigger-30</div>
<div class="font-italic font-color font-bigger">font-italic-nogreen?</div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VHKGL/11/)

Comment: nice, I like the convention, just to clarify, `class="font-italic font-color font-bigger"` means font-italic extends from font-color which extends from font-bigger? you can chain in that way?

Comment: no it means that `div` will contain properties of `.font-italic,.font-color,.font-bigger`

Comment: ok, but what happens for duplicate properties? which decleration takes precedence?

Comment: if you observe the structure, there are no as such duplicate properties

Comment: i know, was curious to know _what_ happens when duplicates exist, I'll play with it, thank you for the info!