# Is it valid to assign a value twice to the same property within one rule?

Tags: css

Consider this:

```
h1 { color: red; color: blue }
```

Or, a more complex example (taken from a SVG file, stroke is twice):

```
style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:20;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke:#555555"
```

It *seems* that the answer is “it’s legal, the last assignment wins”, but I’d really like to know: Is there something written in the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) about this topic?

Comment: Have you tried validating it?
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: But why would you want to use two values for same property?

Comment: @Mirage: I have a program that makes some *small* changes to styles in SVG files, and I’d like to avoid to use a complete CSS parser for this task that seems to be so simple.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is valid to have multiple declarations that assign a value to a property so that the assignments apply to the same element, e.g.

```
h1 { color: red; }
h1 { color: blue }
```

Combining the declarations in the same rule does not change this.

There is no explicit statement about this in CSS specifications, so it is allowed simply because there is no rule that forbids it. Multiple declarations are very common, though mostly so that they are in different rules, often even in distinct style sheets. But they can also be used within a rule. A common technique is

```
 p { max-width: 25em; max-width: 60ch }
```

which means that older browsers that do not recognize the `ch` unit will use the setting `max-width: 25em`, whereas in newer browsers, the latter declaration takes effect.

A general rule in CSS is that all other things being equal, latter declaration wins; this is part of the [cascade rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade). In the case of `h1 { color: red; color: blue }`, all other things are equal. But in `h1 { color: red !important; color: blue }`, the first declaration would win.

Comment: I found it: [Cascading Order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order): "4. Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins."

Answer (score 5):

It is [COMPLETELY VALID](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), `h1 { color: red; color: blue }` here `color` will simply be overridden by the next property value i.e `blue`

[image]

---

Even I use that while my website is in development mode, I often use `border: 1px solid #f00;` to create a blueprint of the page.

Comment: #offtop: you should use `outline` instead of `border` in dev, because it don't change size of elements ;)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't like outlines as I can't set them top right bottom left but actually I've pretty good experience in CSS so can get hold of these stuff well :)

Comment: Nice, it obviously is valid. Is there a proof that the second property will override the first?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I am convinced now :)