# Center align line below text

Tags: html, css

I have a line below my h2 element.

It is left aligned, but I'd like to center align this directly below the text.

Can someone help resolve this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4es6ugjn/

```css
h2 {
  display:block
}

h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Welcome to our Website</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure not to spoil your code in a haste to answer the question.

Comment: Why would you specify the margin twice in your code? That's incorrect

Comment: Thanks I forgot to remove that

Comment: @michaelmcgurk @vedankita There are flaws here. A `display: inline-block` is not required if you are going to absolutely position the line inside. Also, `position: absolute` is unnecessary in this context. A simple `margin: 0 auto` with `display: inline-block` should be the ideal solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use `display: inline-block` on the parent & `margin: auto` on the child.

```css
h2 {
  display:inline-block
}

h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Welcome to our Website</h2>
```

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava No its fine when you are using css properties that can have multiple values i.e a `margin-top` later can override a simple `margin` value. When using the same class across multiple elements its a common practice. In this case it could have been combined. Hence, updated.

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava What is incorrect is you down-voting a perfectly correct answer due to ignorance & lack of knowledge.

Comment: Shobhit Srivastava@ My code  was not semantic, but It does not mean that solution is wrong. and you should not have done downvote :(

Comment: I will let the following links answer for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653771/is-it-valid-to-assign-a-value-twice-to-the-same-property-within-one-rule http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065958/defining-css-properties-twice

Please provide some proof for your argument which anyway is baseless. And the statement up there should be `whose sole purpose`. So far for calling everyone else incorrect! P.S. Ignorance is bliss, but being ignorant of Ignorance is what makes you a jerk.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of using margin as suggested by others, you can set `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`

This method of centering can come in handy when you are unable to use margin, or you have a margin set for another reason.

```css
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Welcome to our Website</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
h2 {
  display:inline-block;

}

h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for this issue

```css
h2 {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2:after {
        border-bottom: 4px solid #ae263d;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Welcome to our Website</h2>
```