# Adding css properties to jquery element has different result - class vs. css() method

Tags: jquery, css

For my site, I'm saving the navigation menu's selected name in a cookie and after postback I read the cookie and then apply a background image to that selected menu item (using the same image I use for hovering).

I made a class for my "selected" menu items:

```
.selected
 {
color: Green;
height: 40px;
background: url(images/menu_hover.jpg) bottom no-repeat; 
 }
```

When I check for a cookie after postback I want to apply this class:

```
$("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("selected");
```

It seems it only applies the background image, *not* the color or the height. In order to have the color and height work at all, I have to explicitly set those using the .css() method:

```
$("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).css({ 'color': "green" });
$("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).css({ 'height': "40px" });
```

Just curious if anyone has an idea as to why this occuring?

Comment: probably you have another class which is over writing them, a link example would be great

Comment: and why you want to do this sort of thing with cookies is beyone me :P

Comment: Are any errors occuring?

Comment: Tomgrohl, no errors to report

Comment: its difficult to suggest a usefull idea, unless you can provide information about your website or cms and coding language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like a css specificity issue -- you may have `color` and `height` defined elsewhere with a more specific selector.

Comment: *bangs head on desk* -- so simple but exactly what it was... I had a specific selector for the anchor tag with a different height defined. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

May it be that other CSS selectors match your element as well and they have higher priority?

You may find more info here: [CSS: Understanding the selector's priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority)

Comment: Thanks Vilmantas, that link points out what I need to understand

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) or [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) in Firefox to work out what's actually affecting your styles.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want to use a class on a specific link when your on that page, so you could have a class on the body, like so:

```
<body class="home">
```

And in your CSS:

```
.home a.homeLink:link{
...
}
```

Wouldn't need JS at all then.

Done an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NbVVr/

Not sure if this is what you want?