# Can't figure out why CSS work like this

Tags: css

How come the `#r3` isn't pink? (see jsfiddle.net/aAqKf/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#r1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px red; }
#r2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px green; }
#r3 { width: 25px; height: 25px; border: solid 1px blue; }

.pink div {
    background: pink;
}

.red div {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="r1" class="red">
    <div id="r2" class="pink">
        <div id="r3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the `pink` class to apply the `pink` background to the `div` children. It doesn't work like that. Why?

Though, it works if I change the CSS as follows (jsfiddle.net/aAqKf/1/):

```
<style>
#r1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px red; }
#r2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px green; }
#r3 { width: 25px; height: 25px; border: solid 1px blue; }

.red div {
    background: red;
}

.pink div {
    background: pink;
}
</style>
```

Please help me figure out how come it works that way. Also, please do not suggest that I use `!important` along with the `background: pink` declaration because [it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/aAqKf/2/) only [until I change the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/aAqKf/3/) as follows:

```
<div id="r1" class="pink">
    <div id="r2" class="red">
        <div id="r3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NB: I am more interested in figuring out why it works that way than finding out how to make it work my way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity/4072434#4072434

Answer (score 2):

Both rules `.pink div` and `.red div` are equally [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). The latter rule overrides the former.

You almost never have to use `!important`, by the way. Using the selector `body .pink div`, or `div.pink div` is enough to give the selector more weight.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html#cascade)

> To make it easy, when two rules have the same weight, the last rule specified wins.

In your first fiddle, the red wins. In the second the pink wins.

Answer (score -1):

Because the properties of class inheritance differ from that of the actual element.

For example, if you changed

```
.pink div { background: pink; }
```

to:

```
#r2 div { background: pink; }
```

it would work as you intended it, because the nested block level elements inherit based on their closest parent.

Classes, on the other hand, have much looser inheritance and properties get overwritten based on the parents, unless specifically said otherwise using !important, when two selectors have the same weight.

To further demonstrate this point, changing `.pink div` to `div.pink div` would also demonstrate the correct effect because, again, CSS is referring to an element and not a class selector.