# Why does the hover pseudo-class override the active pseudo-class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

**The title basically says it all.**

Suppose I have an element which I want to change color on `:hover`, but while clicked, I want it to switch back to its original color. So, I've tried this:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    background: red;
}
a:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

As it turns out, this doesn't work. After a lot of head-scratching, I realized that the `:hover` state was overriding the `:active` state. This was easily solved by this:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    background: green;
}
a:hover {
    background: red;
}
a:active {
    background: green;
}
```

(I could combine the 1st rule with the 3rd one).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V5FUy/

---

My question: is this the expected behavior? As far as I understand this, the `:active` state should always override the `:hover` state, since the `:active` state will *almost* always be accompanied with the `:hover` state.

Comment: This is the (unfortunately) expected behavior. I'm not privy to the origins of this oddity, but it has been this way as long as I can remember (going on 10+ years, now). That said, I think it remains this way because browsers want to remain consistent with eachother. The fact that all browsers respect this order means that the code you write will work in all browsers. I don't disagree with your assessment that :active should always override :hover, though.

Comment: @Brendan - Thanks. You seem to be the only one here that's understanding my question.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the order in which `:active` and `:hover` were added (to CSS1 and CSS2, respectively)... We are seemingly in history territory at this point, and not programming.

Comment: @JosephSilber I think the confusion is you are thinking of :hover and :active as being mutually exclusive. In reality an active anchor link has both pseudo classes when you hover.  So it's getting styled by the first line and overwritten immediately afterwards.  Here is an example using explicit classes [link](http://jsfiddle.net/willyrybone/V5FUy/1/)

Comment: Here's a related question I answered with my iPhone on a day out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371732/why-does-foo-alink-foo-avisited-selector-override-ahover-aactive-se

Comment: For those who struggle to remember the proper ordering of pseudo classes related to `a` tag in a style sheet is - **L**o**V**e before **HA**te. `Link` -> `Visited` -> `Hover` -> `Active`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes this is expected behavior,

lets take a look at another example. just adding two classes,

```
<ul>
<li class="item first">item</li>
<li class="item">item</li>
<li class="item">item</li>
<li class="item">item</li>
<li class="item last">item</li>
</ul>
```

here the class first also comes together with the class item.
but if we declare our css in the wrong order that would not give the wanted behavior

```
.first { background: blue; }
.item { background: red; }
```

as you can see, the last matching selector will be used.
it is the same as your example, no mather what is more logic, 
the 2 pseudo-classes are concidered equal, thus the same rules apply
the last matching defenition wins.

**edit**

pseudoclasses are equals, it is the one defined last that wins! here is a jsFiddle that proves my point :link defined after :hover, :link wins ([test](http://jsfiddle.net/kVLEZ)) so, your statement of :hover overriding :link is wrong, its just the same like with :active, its all about the order.

Comment: You seem to all be missing the point here. You all understand that `:hover` always overrides `:link`, even though it's still a link when you hover. Because everybody understands that if you applied a style to the `:hover` state, you are not interested in the original state. The same logic should apply to the `:active` state...

Comment: As i said, pseudoclasses are equals, it is the one defined last that wins!  here is a jsFiddle that proves my point `:link` defined after `:hover`, `:link` wins  (http://jsfiddle.net/kVLEZ/) so, your statement of `:hover` overriding `:link` is wrong, its just the same like with `:active`, its all about the order.

Comment: For those who find it difficult to remember the proper ordering of pseudo classes related to `a` tag in a style sheet is - **L**o**V**e before **HA**te. `Link` -> `Visited` -> `Hover` -> `Active`

Answer (score 4):

The active state must be declared **after** the hover state, in your CSS you're clumping together the active state **before** the active state so it's not being triggered.

If you state the proper order of operation it works, like below, it works fine.

```
a.noworks:link, a.noworks:visited {
    background: red;
}

a.noworks:hover {
    background: green;
}

a.noworks:active {
    background: red;
}
```

So, to answer your question, yes this is the expected behavior.

Here is the order of operation:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

Comment: You seem to all be missing the point here. You all understand that `:hover` always overrides `:link`, even though it's still a link when you hover. Because everybody understands that if you applied a style to the `:hover` state, you are not interested in the original state. The same logic should apply to the `:active` state...

Comment: The links follow an order of operation, you can't overwrite something out of order. Predefined conditions have to be met for the order of operation to function. 1. Is it a link? if yes, apply said color. 2. Has it been visited? if yes, applied said color. 3. Is the link being hovered? Apply said color. 4. Has the link been clicked (activated)? If yes, apply said color. You can't break out of that sequence, otherwise it would make the whole link styling process moot. It's like driving a car without first starting it.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first code you defined `:hover` after you defined `:active`, so `:hover` "overwrote" `:active`. In the second, it's the other way around, `:active` overwrites `:hover`.

Comment: You seem to all be missing the point here. You all understand that `:hover` always overrides `:link`, even though it's still a link when you hover. Because everybody understands that if you applied a style to the `:hover` state, you are not interested in the original state. The same logic should apply to the `:active` state...

Comment: You're missing the point. Since you defined `:link` first, `:hover` overwrites it. If you put `:hover` first then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Sorry, I misunderstand the question.

Basically when you are in active state (with a mouse pointer) you are actually in hover state too. So based on CSS rules it would read the last one in stylesheet.

When you hover over a link and hold down the mouse key It's like this if we take pseud classes as normal classes :

```
<a class="active hover"></a>
```

So if your css was

```
.active{color:green}
.hover{color:red}
```

it would apply red

but if your css was

```
.hover{color:red}
.active{color:green}
```

It would apply green

From [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)

> ```
> a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
> a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
> a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
> a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
> ```
>
> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited
>   rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color'
>   property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed
>   after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both
>   activates and hovers over the A element.

Comment: You're still missing the point. Read the last line of the question!

Comment: You are once again missing the point. I know that while being in the `:active` state I'm also in the `:hover` state. I've clearly stated that in my question. What I'm trying to understand is this: Why do these 2 pseudo-classes share the same specificity weight? In my opinion, `:active` should always override `:hover` precisely ***because*** you always `:hover` while being `:active`!!!!

Comment: You seem to all be missing the point here. You all understand that `:hover` always overrides `:link`, even though it's still a link when you hover. Because everybody understands that if you applied a style to the `:hover` state, you are not interested in the original state. The same logic should apply to the `:active` state...

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works, and I'll try to explain why.  As we know CSS will continue searching the document when applying styles and apply the style that is most specific to the element.

Example:

```
li.betterList { better list styling here }
```

Is more specific and will overwrite

```
li { list styling here }
```

And these Puesdo selectors are all considered the same specificity and thus the last line will overwrite the previous one.  This is confirmed by the note on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

> **Note:** :active MUST come after :hover (if present) in the CSS definition in order to be effective!

you can also throw this CSS on your jsfidle  and watch it overwrite since they are the same specificity

```
.works {background: red}
.works {background: green}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the *expected behavior* in so far as most people always place the `:hover` pseudo-class at the end of the group of rules.

Order of declaration matters with pseudo-classes (see more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses), so the final rules get precedence, as with other rules in CSS.

For most people, I think the desired behavior:

```
a:link {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:visited {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:hover {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Since the `:active` is not so useful it is left out... or combined with `a:link` and `a:visited`... and then it is overridden by `a:hover`

W3C spells it out here:

> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited
>   rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color'
>   property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed
>   after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both
>   activates and hovers over the A element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

Even W3schools gets this one right:

> Note: a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS
>   definition in order to be effective!!
>
> Note: a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order
>   to be effective!!

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should at least consider the *flow* of User Interaction on links *(or buttons)*.

Usually,

1. `:link` has always been the default *(untouched)*,
2. Then when a User points to the button, then that is where `:hover` comes into play.
3. Once a User points to the link or button, then he/she will click, that is where `:active` comes in.

That is the standard sequence of how we interact with links *(or buttons)*. With the exception of `:visited`, where the result is only obvious when the User has previously pressed the link.

It would be really helpful if you keep in mind the mnemonic: ' **L** o **V** e **H A** t e ' when dealing on links *(except for `:visited`, which doesn't work for buttons)*.

However, if you really want to do an override, say, you want to change the color of a link that was already visited on active state, you can do something like:

```
a:visited:active {
     color: red;   
}
```

But the bottom line is, avoid changing the standard sequence if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the :active pseudo-class override the :hover pseudo-class regardless of the order of declaration by using the :not() selector.

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    background: red;
}

a:hover:not(:active) {
    background: green;
}
```

This way, the :hover selector is triggered only when the :active selector is not.