# Button Not Active Until Mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I'd like to say right off the bat that THIS IS NOT A CSS PROBLEM.  The following is simply to demonstrate with css the kind of problem I'm having.

In an html page filled with javascript and css, there is a `<div>` tag with the following styling:

```
div {
  background-color:#fff;
}
div:hover {
  background-color:#f00;
}
div:active {
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Point being, I can tell when the element is being hovered because the background will be red, and I can tell when it is clicked because the background will be black.

What's happening is that the hover styling works, but when I click the element, it doesn't change to the active state until, still holding the mouse button down, I pull the mouse out of the element.

This is probably a result of my messing around with the event handlers on the page, but I'm just wondering if anyone else has come across this phenomenon and knows what it might be.

**Edit**

Here's what I'm working on: http://faithserve.com/jOS/

Click the "App" Menu, and click start.  That button-ish thing is what I'm having the problem with.

Comment: Some browsers only support :active & :hover on anchor elements. I'd suggest adding .hover on .hover() and .active/.clicked .on('click');

Comment: This is Google Chrome.  And the :active styling is showing up, just not until the mouse is pulled out from over the `<div>`

Comment: works here or i don't understand your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/UDwRn/

Comment: Yes, thing is I'm doing a lot of work with other css and event handlers, and I'm not sure where I messed up.  I'm just checking to see if anyone has seen this before since it's kinda strange and might know generally what kind of problem I'm having

Comment: From the docs `:active - When interacting with a mouse, this is typically the time between the user presses the mouse button and releases it. `

Comment: I've edited my question.  I'm not having trouble with the css, I'm having trouble with the Javascript, and the css I put up there is just to demonstrate the kind of problem I'm having.

Comment: @SamuelReid I don't understand, how is it related to javascript?

Comment: Check your CSS file, you are setting :active before :hover ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the order of the css definitions. States have a particular order in which they need to be defined. See the end bit of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508202/476786

> ```
> a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
> a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
> a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
> a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
> ```
>
> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited
>   rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color'
>   property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed
>   after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both
>   activates and hovers over the A element.

In your question you have them the correct way, so it can't be repro'd, whereas I have a demo here which shows the wrong way too: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/nbW6L/

```
/* Right */
div.right {
  background-color:#fff;
}
div.right:hover {
  background-color:#f00;
}
div.right:active {
  background-color:#000;
}

/* Wrong */
div.wrong {
  background-color:#fff;
}
div.wrong:active {
  background-color:#000;
}
div.wrong:hover {
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure CSS rule `:hover` is setted before `:active`. You could use that instead of just `:active` :

```
div:hover:active {
  background-color:#000;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UDwRn/1/)