# Scroll the text data on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, mousehover

I want to display the text data on hover of the `warning icon` which should have scroll and we can scroll up and down through the data contained in the hover box ...I know it's possible to do but unable to get anything on web.. Till now i am able to display the data being initialized in the controller part but i am unable to set the scroll and hold the text appearance.

https://plnkr.co/edit/IhS8Nn9VCgFgucAHmckW?p=preview

Comment: you mean scroll the title?

Comment: yeah you can say that...pls checkout the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an angular solution, but you could produce the desired effect with a bit of css. Just add a new class to your span (I used `fa-warning--custom`) and put some new css in your css file.

If you want to hard-code the warning into the css's `content` attribute you can, but the `attr(title)` solution does work with the handlebars data, at least in the Plunker.

Note that both the title solution and the css popup appear at once. You can fix this by changing the name of the `span`'s `title` attribute to something else, like `data-title`, but be sure to make the same change in `attr()` in the css.

Because this is all css, you can modify and customize the hover block however you'd like.

```css
.fa-warning--custom {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fa-warning--custom::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  
}

.fa-warning--custom:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

/* the following css is for demonstration, you don't need it */

.fa-warning--custom {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.tile {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<span class="tile"><span ng-if=true  class="fa fa-warning fa-warning--custom" style="font-size:15px;color:red" title="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">!</span></span>
<span class="tile"><span ng-if=true  class="fa fa-warning fa-warning--custom" style="font-size:15px;color:red" title="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">!</span></span>
```

Comment: it's working but i am placing this icon on a `tile` and `tiles` are generated using `ng-repeat` so the hover is getting overridden by the next tile is there any solution for this?

Comment: I only have a bit of experience with Angular, and so I'm not sure how to deal with that. Are you able to put an expanded example that uses tiling on Plunker?

Comment: I think this is the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508145/why-does-the-hover-pseudo-class-override-the-active-pseudo-class

Comment: Oh, by overridden do you mean that the hover element is actually below the adjacent tile? If that's the case, then I think adding `z-index: 3;` (3 is somewhat arbitrary, any number above 1 should work) to `.fa-warning--custom::after` should work. I'll update my snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a stacking context issue, but if it is, then it's difficult to solve without knowing the full stack of elements and their `position`s and z-indices. You might try `.<some class that is on the parent tile>:hover { z-index: 15;}`

Comment: When you say overriden: does the hover element appear, but below the next tile? Does nothing appear? Does the hover element of another tile appear? Does something else happen?

Comment: hover element appear, but below the next tile?...yes this is the case..

Answer (score 1):

I think the scrolling does not work with tooltips, but multiline can be done this way:

```
$scope.hoverData = $scope.hoverData.match(/.{1,10}/g).join("\n")
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jh2jZaPlUVYdNFWHzHN5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this instead of tooltip

```
 <style>
  #hoveredText {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display:none;
  }

  #warningText {
    position: relative;
  }

  #warningText span:hover + #hoveredText {
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

HTML code would be :

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<span id="warningText"> 
  <span ng-if="true"  class="fa fa-warning" style="font-size:15px;color:red"></span>
  <div id="hoveredText">
    <pre>
      Dummy text
      Dummy text
      Dummy textDummy text

      Dummy text
      Dummy text
      Dummy text
    </pre>
  </div>
</span>
```