# CSS selectors and pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Say for example I have the following styles:

```
#HorizNav ul li a.active:link { background-color: #FFF; }
#HorizNav ul li a.active:visited { background-color: #FFF; }
#HorizNav ul li a.active:active { background-color: #FFF; }
#HorizNav ul li a.active:hover { background-color: #FFF; }
```

If all the styles are the same, then how would I group these styles together?

Would it be like this?

```
#HorizNav ul li a.active:link, a.active:visited, a.active:active, a.active:hover { }
```

Comment: What if you ditched the pseudo-classes altogether? (`:hover` should come before `:active` by the way.)

Comment: thnx, but why does the order of pseudo-classes matter?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371846/106224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler

```
#HorizNav ul li a.active { background-color: #FFF; }
```

Comment: I'd guess that you really don't need that much specificity and `#HorizNav a.active { background-color: #FFF; }` would suffice and increase the speed of the selector.

Comment: @steveax: It also decreases the specificity, potentially making it unbalanced.