# Why can't a C# lambda expression consist of a simple if statement, without needing braces?

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider the following lambda expression that is being assigned to an event.

```
foo.BarEvent += (s, e) => if (e.Value == true) DoSomething();
```

This appears pretty straight-forward and consists of only one line of code.  So why am I getting the following 2 errors from the debugger?

> Invalid expression term 'if'

---

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

To fix this problem, all you have to do is a wrap your `if` statement in brackets.

```
foo.BarEvent += (s, e) => { if (e.Value == true) DoSomething(); };
//Errors now disappear!
```

I understand what these error messages are stating.  What I don't understand is why a single-condition `if` statement would be a problem for the compiler and why the first lambda assignment is considered broken.

Could someone please explain the problem?

Comment: You consider a conditional AND  function call a single statement?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Ok, yes, I understand your point.  However, this is a single, 1-line statement, from the perspective that each C# "statement" must end with a semi-colon.  If my term is incorrect, please elaborate.  I don't mind making a minor update to reflect the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: On the other hand, why should it be allowed? As Eric Lippert is fond of pointing out, all features are unimplemented by default.

Comment: @RLH Could you convert that into a ternary operation?

Comment: Well, I just started using lambdas about 2 weeks ago (I've unfortunately been stuck in 2004 for to long!)  That's why I'm asking these questions.  I just assumed that any "statement" (or whatever you want to call it, that consists of one line of code, could be implemented as a lambda, without the bracket wrapper.

Comment: @AndreCalil Sure, there's always away to make something a ternary statement.  However, wrapping my expression with brackets isn't a problem, which is actually takes much fewer characters.  However, I'm trying to figure out why this necessary to begin with.

Comment: Lambdas are, an expression or a statement block. Your example is a statement block.. so thats pretty much the answer.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead To your first comment, yes, actually it *is* a single statement.  It's just not an expression, which is why it needs to be a statement lambda and not an expression lambda.

Comment: @Servy: isn't it referred to as a "Compound Statement"? It has two parts.. a conditional and a function call.. happy to be wrong.. just always thought there was a defined difference.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It is made up of more than one expression, but it is not two statements.  Two statements would have more than one semicolon.

Comment: @RLH I believe that a ternary operation is considered as a single expression. Thus, you wouldn't need the braces

Comment: @AndreCalil No, it's a single *expression*, and is *not* a statement.  Thus is can be used for an expression lambda rather than a statement lambda.

Comment: btw, you need not `== true`

Comment: Thanks @Servy. Good to get my terminology straight :)

Comment: @RiaD: I'm just trying to give explicit sample code.  Yes, I'm well aware that if you ever use any conditional statement that looks like `... == true` or `... == false`, your doing it wrong.

Comment: By the way, adding this feature would introduce yet more dangling else problems to the language.

Comment: @RiaD Maybe `e.Value` is a nullable bool?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Without `{ }` you declare an expression body, with `{ }` it's a statement body. See [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx):

- An [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx) lambda returns the result of the expression
- A [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx) lambda resembles an expression lambda except that the statement(s) is enclosed in braces [...] The body of a statement lambda can consist of any number of statements.

So, if you want a statement rather than an expression, use braces.

Comment: So much faster than me typing on my phone!! +1

Comment: It's not "if you want more than one statement ....", it's more simply "if you want a *statement* rather than an *expression* ..."

Comment: I see.  This certainly helps clarify the situation.  So the bottom line is, if the "line of code" doesn't evaluate to a final value, wrap it in brackets.  I assume this is because the compiler interprets the brackets to really mean `void (s, e) { ...}` which is returning a `void` pointer after operation.

Comment: @RLH I think it would help understand the issue better if you read more about statements and expressions and what's the difference between the two.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I still mix up the terminology sometimes, thanks. I meant to say a statement exists out of one or more expressions, but that also isn't true (ref. [Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx)).

Comment: @RLH It doesn't need to be void at all.  It can have a `return` keyword within it.  Likewise, an expression lambda can resolve to `void` easily enough.

Comment: A `return` statement is, essentially, a `return void;` statement.  Well, it is for most languages. I'd assume this is true for C# as well but I haven't dug in the documentation to verify.

Comment: @RLH You miss the point entirely.  I could have a statement such as `()=>{return 0;}`.  A statement lambda doesn't need to be void returning.  Likewise, an expression lambda *can* be void returning, i.e. `()=>someVoidMethod`.  Either lambda type can return a value, or be `void`.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: [:3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371732/why-does-foo-alink-foo-avisited-selector-override-ahover-aactive-s/7371846#7371846)

Comment: @Servy, I do understand but forgive me if I'm not stating this clearly. I was initially stating that "I get it now". The difference between a "statement" and an "expression" is that the expression evaluates to something being returned (or returnable) by the code. In the case of an if-block, nothing is being returned. When you wrap your code in `{}` this converts the statement to an expression because the brackets essentially define a block of code that returns `void` which an if-block does not do. It doesn't have to be `void` but it does need to return *something*.

Comment: @RLH And I'm saying that's false.  An expression, and thus an expression lambda, does not need to return a value.  This snippet: `()=> Console.WriteLine("hi");` creates an expression lambda for an expression that has no return value at all.  The reason you can't use an `if` isn't because it doesn't return a value; it's because the grammar of C# simply states that an `if` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @Servy: After reading your claims, I decided to ask and do a bit more research (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260043/return-nothing-or-return-void-what-exactly-does-c-sharp-do-at-the-end-of-a-voi) What?! After reading Reed's response, I assume that the braces around the lambda code "signal" to the compiler that the code might not return a value and is, thus, a series of statements. I feel like I'm going further down this rabbit hole than I intended, but in a good way. Thanks for the push-back. It's made this endeavour quite informative.

Comment: @RLH They signal no such thing.  For an expression lambda it looks at the return value (if any) of that expression and uses that.  By enclosing the expression in braces you force it to be a statement, in which the return value of the statement block is whatever is returned via `return`.  It doesn't change the fact that either a statement or an expression lambda can be void or can return a value.

Comment: When you don't declare { } compiler expects some value that can be returned by default, you cannot return if. In Ruby for comparison  everything return result, but not in C#.

Answer (score 9):

See [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).

There are two *types* of lambdas, Expression Lambdas (no `{}`) and Statement Lambdas (with `{}`).

The key difference between them is that Expression Lambdas are defined to return the *value* computed by their right hand side. But `if()` is a statement, not an expression. There's no value associated with an `if`. You'll notice that all of the "allowed" language elements in the error message you provide are *expressions*: they compute a *value*.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, it would not be a problem to implement this. The C# team have already implemented way scarier functionalities (LINQ for example)

But the problem is where do you draw the line?

if

```
b => if (b) DoSomething()`
```

is allowed, then, why shouldn't

```
b => if (b) {DoSomething1(); DoSomething2();}
```

be allowed. Or

```
list => foreach (var item in list) DoSomething(item)
```

etc, etc, etc...
And before you know it, you have a whole team supporting a basically trivial feature.

The only sure way not to have bugs in a feature is to [not implement the feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx).

The current implementation is the optimum, as it works in the majority of cases, and it's not too cumbersome in the rest of them (a simple {} does not hinder readability too much, while making it easier for the compiler).

Comment: Could you explain what you consider scarey in LINQ?

Comment: It's almost like adding a second language within the language. Parsing it and transforming it in a deterministic way, and providing intelisense for it is, IMHO, tough to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this this way.  You have a conditional statement that fires one line if correct.

`if (stuff) do stuff;`

Which can also be written

```
if (stuff)
     do stuff;
```

Because you're only calling one line of code you don't need two brackets. If it were more, then you would have to use brackets.

```
if (stuff)
{
     do stuff;
     do more stuff;
}
```

Then you're combining it with an anonymous method, that behaves in a similar fashion

```
() => do stuff;
```

More than one statement, uses brackets just like the conditional.

```
() => {do stuff; do more stuff;}
```

But now you're nesting them, but still expecting to be able to use the short cut.
Which is really what it is, a short cut that implies the brackets for one single statement.

So you're nesting one shortcut inside of another shortcut.  C# is just making forcing you to explicitly spell out the nested shortcut.

Comment: Yes and no. You are again (as a lot of people do) defining the requirement in "lines of code". The real definition is a case of expression vs. statement.