# One style selector to specify both hover,active within a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to write a style for the following:

I only want to style a:hover and a:active for the anchor tags inside .menu, not .menu-switch. The below appears to be working, but is there anyway I can join them into one style?

```css
/*Apply the following styles to anchor tags within any ul within #main-nav*/
#main-nav ul li
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Apply the following styles to anchor tags within .menu only within #main-nav*/
#main-nav .menu a:active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#main-nav .menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu-switch">
        <li><a class="js-menu-toggle" href="#">OPEN ME</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually has one other problem: the first set of CSS rules are not being grouped correctly. You need to repeat the `#main-nav ul li` portion for every selector in the list; otherwise, the rules will apply to other links in the document, not just the ones in `#main-nav ul li`.

In the same vein, to group your last two rules you need to group their selectors in their entirety.

Also, in case you weren't aware of it, you probably want to [follow the LoVe-HAte mnemonic in arranging your link pseudo-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371732/why-does-foo-alink-foo-avisited-selector-override-ahover-aactive-s/7371846#7371846), unless you have a good reason to sort `:visited` after `:hover` and `:active` (I've also taken the time to arrange your last two selectors in the same order).

```css
/*Apply the following styles to anchor tags within any ul within #main-nav*/
#main-nav ul li a:link,
#main-nav ul li a:visited,
#main-nav ul li a:hover,
#main-nav ul li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Apply the following styles to anchor tags within .menu only within #main-nav*/
#main-nav .menu a:hover,
#main-nav .menu a:active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu-switch">
        <li><a class="js-menu-toggle" href="#">OPEN ME</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
#main-nav ul li a:link,
#main-nav ul li a:hover,
#main-nav ul li a:active,
#main-nav ul li a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
    /*Apply the following styles to anchor tags within .menu only within #main-nav*/
#main-nav ul a:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
}

#main-nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
  <ul class="menu-switch">
    <li><a class="js-menu-toggle" href="#">OPEN ME</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```