# jquery toggle animation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hey so im trying to make this box animate up and then when you click it again to animate back to its original position but its just not working
here is the non working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyP9A/67/

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your css isn't specific enough. Making `.sky1` `div#sky.sky1` makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your JS Fiddle is that the #sky css code is overwriting the .sky1 class due to [CSS Selectors Priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity).

I edited your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyP9A/71/) and changed #sky to .sky and thus .sky and .sky1 have the same priority and since .sky1 is later in the CSS code it overwrites .sky :) Hope that solved your problem!

Comment: this works perfectly on the jsfiddle but when i put it into my html the transition is very choppy, there is no animation it just turns into the other class. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The Transition between the class changes comes with the jquery UI on the JSFiddle. [link](http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass/). Since you had checked jqueryUI on your fiddle I kept it in my fiddle. You could use .animate() but then you would have to specify all the values to change and check on which one is active.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin said, you ran into an issue with css [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).  `#sky` has a higher specificity than `.sky1` which causes it to not compute correctly.  To fix this issue you need to create a selector with higher specificity than `#sky`, for example `#sky.sky1` should do the trick

*Side note:*
You do not need to query the dom a second time in your `.click()`, you can simiply use `$(this)`

```
$(function() {
    $("#sky").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sky1");
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fyP9A/75/)

Comment: this works perfectly on the jsfiddle but when i put it into my html the transition is very choppy, there is no animation it just turns into the other class. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Adjust the fiddle with your actual code and I might be able to help further.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fyP9A/78/
it works perfect in the fiddle, but it doesnt animate in my actual html.