# Overwrite rules of h4 with a class selector

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
      <h4 class="test"> Test </h4>
  </div>
</div>​
```

And the following CSS:

```
.main .container h4 {
 color: red;   

}
.test {
 color: blue;   
}
```

Why would the class .test not overwrite the color rule? How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

​

Comment: You must understand the css selectors priority. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [***specificity***](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue.

Specificity is how important a certain selector is. In this case your first declaration uses two classes, and an element. This means only an inline style, #id or something with more classes can over write it.

If you want to affect the class `test`, we can use `.main .container .test`, this is 3 classes and will now over write it!

If two things have the same specificity, for example if you use `.main .container h4` again, the one that comes last in the document will take precedence.

There is a way to over write regardless of your specificity or where it comes in the document, and that is by adding `!important` to a certain style, for example `.test { color: blue !important; }`. This is not recommended if you can use what is described above as this may cause future issues.

The spec can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
> - The specificity is based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.