# Priority of one css attribute value over another

Tags: css, jquery-ui

For a button I have 3 possible classes: "state-normal", "state-focus" and "state-hover".
All have the same attributes (background, border, ...), but different values for the
attributes.
If a button gets "state-focus", I do not want to remove the class "state-normal".
If a button is "state-focus" and gets "state-hover", I do not want to remove the class
"state-focus".
In the browser language specification you can give a "quality"/priority to a language:

```
"Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7"
```

It would be great to do the same also in css:

```
.state-normal { background-color: #aaaaaa;q=0.5 }
.state-focus  { background-color: #bbbbbb;q=0.7 }
.state-hover  { background-color: #eeeeee;q=0.9 }
```

I know that there is nothing in CSS.

But, I know in jQuery UI they have kind of this, because they don't remove "ui-state-default" when they assign "ui-state-focus" to an element. How do they do it?

Is there another way to implement this with a trick (WITHOUT !IMPORTANT).

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using CSS.

```
.state-normal { background-color: #aaaaaa;q=0.5 }
.state-normal.state-focus  { background-color: #bbbbbb;q=0.7 }
.state-focus.state-hover  { background-color: #eeeeee;q=0.9 }
```

But this implies that all classes mentioned in the rule will be present, i.e. an element will have both classes present. So an element with class `state-focus` will not have the background-color set as per the rule.

If you want to avoid that, then you can do this instead:

```
.state-normal { background-color: #aaaaaa;q=0.5 }
.state-focus, .state-normal.state-focus  { background-color: #bbbbbb;q=0.7 }
.state-hover, .state-focus.state-hover  { background-color: #eeeeee;q=0.9 }
```

---

EDIT: As per OP's request

[CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

[CSS Selectors - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors)

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity)

Comment: Thank you, Vimal Stan. Can you give me a link to a info page about this.

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec Glad I could help, added links to the answer.