# Custom CSS not working when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my angular application set up and everything is working. I am trying to add some custom css to input so I made a new file my.css

```
.myInvalid {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

I have added that file to my index.html and the file gets loaded but when I write 
`<input type="text" class="myInvalid"/>` there isn't any border around my input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="MainApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/css/my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="Content/assets/bootmetro/css/bootmetro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/assets/bootmetro/css/bootmetro-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/assets/bootmetro/css/bootmetro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/assets/bootmetro/css/bootmetro-ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
   <input type="text" class="myInvalid"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If I write my css inline `<input type="text" style="border: 5px solid red" />` everything works. The behavior is the same in all browsers.  Any ideas?

Comment: does firebug output errors? the only incorrect thing I see now is "type=text/css". it shouldn't be there according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.6

Comment: I have removed "type=text/css" but it didn't help. No errors in firebug.

Comment: not even in the network tab? maybe you can move the line to the end of the header so that you are 100% sure that your rule is not overwriten

Comment: no errors in firebug.. GET my.css 200 OK :)  I have moved the line to the end of the head and still no change

Comment: when I comment out <link href="Content/assets/bootmetro/css/bootmetro.css" rel="stylesheet" /> I get 5px border but it is grey. And I commented bootmetro-ui-light.css as well and now my boreder is showing.. I must point out that bootmetro.css files are loaded at the begining of the head and my.css is on the last line of the head.

Comment: you can inspect the `input` element with Firebug to know what css rules are overwriting yours.

Comment: This is in no way an angular js question

Comment: Try moving your css include line below the Bootstap line. If that doesn't work, try a more specific selector (i.e. making it "longer" and therefore higher in precedence)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your selector is more specific than the bootstrap one,

Instead of `.myInvalid` use `input[type='text'].myInvalid`

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072434/1401094) for more about selector priority.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem. Do the other stylesheets you're including define styles for `<input type="text">`? If you define your style block as follows, I bet you see your red border:

```
.myInvalid {
    border: 5px solid red !important;
}
```

I'm not saying adding `!important` is the solution, but if it works you know your selector (`.myInvalid`) isn't specific enough to override other styles defined for this element.

You'll need to inspect your `<input>` from the browser and see what style declarations are matching it and overriding the properties you're trying to set. Then you can adjust your selector accordingly.

Comment: He can avoid !important all together by making his selectors "longer"

Comment: "Longer" means nothing. He has to make it more **specific**. For example, if he were to add an ID like `<input type="text" id="myInput">` he could then use `#myInput { border: 5px solid red; }` successfully.

Comment: @PatsyIssa That's not necessarily true.

Comment: Alright for the sake of proper word usage i m changing longer to specific :D