# drop down menu not appearing when using inherited class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create css dropdown menu. I am trying with following html and css

```css
 .nav > li{
    display: inline-block;   
}
.nav{
    background-color: #666666;
}
.nav a{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav .subnav .subs{
    display: none;
}

.subs{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #444;
}
.subs a{
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}

li:hover > ul  {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="subnav">
        <a href="#">Courses</a>
        <ul class="subs">
            <li><a href="#">B.tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BSC</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Above code doesn't work because of I am selecting .subs like `.nav .subnav .subs`

```
.nav .subnav .subs{
    display: none;
}
```

But if I just do

```
.subs{
    display:none;
}
```

It works fine. My question is why its not working if I select element like `.nav .subnav .subs` ? and what difference.

Comment: It is because of CSS selector's priority / specificity. Read this question for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the selectors specificity. You need to be more specific in selectors when using different rules for same elements. Instead of

```
li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Try:

```
li.subnav:hover > ul.subs {
    display: block;
}
```

i.e. more specific selector which targets the element.

If this doesn't work then you may use `!important`. I will not suggest you to go for this option. Better make the CSS selectors more specific.