# CSS spec: properties specified multiple times

Tags: css

Disclaimer: I know this is a bad idea and I'd never do it myself, but I'm trying to figure out what the CSS spec says.

If I have CSS like:

```
span { color: 'red'; color: 'green'; }
```

which one wins?  The first one, the last one, a random one picked by my browser?

And related, if they're redundant but not equivalent, like:

```
span { border-top-width: 10px; border-width: 5px; }
```

does this parse exactly as if I'd said:

```
span { border-top-width: 10px; border-top-width: 5px; border-right-width: 5px; border-bottom-width: 5px; border-left-width: 5px; }
```

and then the previous rule applies?  Or is there a different rule that applies with redundant-but-not-equivalent CSS properties like this?

I've been digging through the CSS spec and I can't seem to find anything that directly applies here.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cascades to the last valid declaration.
So - color:'green' would win.

Again, cascade wins. `border-top-width` would otherwise be styled independently, but `border-width:` would win to apply 5px to All.

Comment: Agreed. For rules of equal specificity, the farthest one down the page wins

Answer (score 1):

The last one always wins...

There are a few rules about priorities that everyone should know...

These are priorities that css follows:

1. css propertie marked as "!important" -> always come first
2. Inline code
3. On page
4. On external file

And then the last one declared on the file.

Best reference: [CSS: Understanding the selector's priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity)

Another good one: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/

Hope it helps.