# CSS inherit between parent and child class

Tags: css

I'm looking for some code improvments and I would like to know something. 
I have this code structure :

```
<div class="container exports">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="title">Export to .csv files</legend>
              ...
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the legend color which is defined in white by default to black. But I don't want to affect other legends.

So in my css code, I have this :

```
legend {
    color: black;
}
```

It change color for all legends.

But when I write this :

```
.exports legend.title {
    color: black;
}
```

It doesn't apply my specific legend in black color.

Why ?

Comment: The code in your question works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/y4xfek52/1// [Use your browsers developer tools to view the styles that are applied to the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689619/how-do-you-determine-what-is-overriding-your-style).

Answer (score -1):

To me, your code should work (example with blue).

You must have another property that overwrites this one. Can you check this ?

```css
.exports legend.title {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container exports">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="title">Export to .csv files</legend>
              ...
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. legend is defined inside a global bootstrap library in my project. But locally, I would like to make some changes.

Comment: Did you check, as I said (using a debugging tool) that there is no other property override this one ?

Comment: How I could make mine to override others ?

Comment: As Marco said, you should be more precise on your selector, or you can place your CSS after others. I'll wont tell you to use "!important", it's better to find a clean way to do this. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance)

Answer (score -1):

A possible mistake could be that you are saying

```
.exports legend.title { color: black; }
```

before the general legend color specification or another css file is overwriting it...
You have two ways:

1. Place your specific legend color after the generic one or refernce the mistaken css after yours
2. use `!important` to overwrite all rules (i don't recommend that way because everytime you want to overwrite that rule, you have to use `!important` again):

   `.exports legend.title { color: black !important; }`

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this method. 
**.exports legend.title{ color:#ff0000;}** And it's working for me.

```css
.exports legend.title{ color:#ff0000;}
```

```html
<div class="container exports">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="title">Export to .csv files</legend>
              ...
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="">Export to .csv files</legend>
              ...
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same here it works with given code. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Is there any other styles overwriting this style?

Comment: without knowing that we can't help him.. :)