# Why is width not taking effect within my media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have never run into this issue before, but for some reason, I cannot modify the width in my media query. In the developer tools, the width shows as being crossed out like I toggled it to not show, but that is not the case, it does it by default.

I am simple trying to change this:

```
div.wrapper{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

into this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
}
```

I have even tried changing my media query `wrapper` class to `div.wrapper`...but it did not help,

What would be causing this?

[image]

Comment: I believe that to be the case. I added a screen shot.

Comment: Is your media query called before or after the other part of CSS that erase it ?

Comment: The media query is after the original style sheet.

Comment: I just added a new image. Would having the main css structured as `.column .sponsors` effect being able to modify `sponsors` in my media query? Would it partially take on what `column` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css if we call an element like attribute.classname(div.wrapper) it will have more priority than calling .classname(.wrapper).

now you have two ways to solve this.

1. Change the calling method (use same way of calling in main-css and media-query).
2. Else give an adiitional property '!important' after width in .wrapper .

   .wrapper {
       width: 95% !important;
       margin: 0 2.5%;
   }

Comment: I just added a new image. Would having the main css structured as `.column .sponsors` effect being able to modify `sponsors` in my media query? Would it partially take on what `column` is?

Comment: Whats happening here is 'layout.css' will over writing the styles of 'index.php'.
It may be also due to the arrangement of linking style sheet too. The bottom most one will over write the styles of top ones.
so please check the arrangement of linking style sheets.
If still the problem is there add !important with the width of .wrapper 

.wrapper {
    width: 95%!important ,
    margin: 0 2.5%,
}

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read this article:
[CSS: Understanding the selector's priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity)

There's priority when you use CSS rules.

For example, `.column .sponsors` will have priority on just `.sponsors`

Answer (score 1):

In your media query, use the same definition than previously:

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your .column .sponsors problem, you should do the same:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    .column .sponsors {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

This will not modify the .column declaration.