# Basic CSS specificity hierarchy

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I think I get CSS specificity, but this particular case is throwing me:

```css
li:first-child {color:  blue}                /* 3 */
div li {color:  red}                         /* 5 [R2] */
div.widget  ul#todo {color:  cyan}           /* 1 [R3] */

div > ul#todo .important {color:  green}     /* 1 */
ul li.postponed {color:  inherit}            /* 2 */
li + li + li {color:  magenta}               /* 4 */
```

```html
<div  class="widget">
    <ul id="todo">
       <li>Buy  Bread</li>
       <li>Learn  Guitar </li>
       <li  class="important">Pay  Bills</li>
       <li  class="postponed">Wash  Car</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I wrote the specificity of the selectors at the side. 
I though the colors of the list (per line) should be 
     cyan 
     cyan 
     green 
     cyan 
 
but it comes out as 
     blue 
     red 
     green 
cyan

I don't understand how R2, with the smaller specificity, can override R3, with the bigger! Could someone explain it, please?

Comment: The code doesn't perform how you say it does. It's coming out blue, red, green, cyan, as the Snippet demonstrates. Also what is the significance of the R# comments?

Comment: Also, this is probably a duplicate, but I can't find one right now. Basically: class selectors are always more specific than tag selectors, and ID selectors are always more specific than class selectors. Read [this article on specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), it might help you.

Comment: Oh, I wrote it wrong. I'll edit it. 
The R# comments are for mentioning the lines later in the text, but I suppose I only need 2 Rs for that. I'll change it too, thanks!

Comment: One way to test this easily is to put the code in JSFiddle and then add in one line of CSS (one selector) at a time, hit Run, and see what changes.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for the links and the help with editing :) The thing is I wanted to understand why the specificity was being overwritten, I already knew the output. I searched, but apparently I missed that detail about multiple targeting. It's all sorted out now ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Understanding the selector's priority / specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specificity is about resolution for different rules for the ***same*** element. But here one sets for `ul` (R3) and the other (R2) for `li`, so the `li` takes precedence in color over its parent's rule which you think coincides.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple
>   declarations.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I didn't know that detail, thank you :D

Comment: And the inherited style, selector #5, is inheriting its color (cyan) from the parent, which is set by selector #3.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all... the outcome is `blue, red, green, cyan`, not `red, red, ...`
2. **Avoid using complex selectors.** Notice that if you simplify them to:

```css
li:first-child {color:  blue}                /* R1 - 3*/
li {color:  red}                             /* R2 - 5*/
#todo {color:  cyan}                         /* R3 - 1*/
.important {color:  green}                   /* R4 - 1*/
.postponed {color:  inherit}                 /* R5 - 2*/
li + li + li {color:  magenta}               /* R6 - 4*/
```

The outcome will be **exactly the same.**

3. To your question, there's a *proximity* issue, a style for `<ul>` will always lose to a style for `<li>` (when styling `<li>` elements).

Comment: "Don't use complex selectors at all." Depends on what you mean by "complex selectors". li + li + li is a complex selector because it contains combinators. But *every* selector here is also a complex selector, even if it only contains one compound selector.

Comment: @BoltClock I toned it down a bit. The example went to show that most overly complex selectors are fruit of poor programming.