# Why would CSS ignore selector under attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a button: `<button class="outline">Outline</button>` which I want to set the outline on, but all of the other buttons should not have outline.

If give it a class `b1` and do:

```
[dir="ltr"] .b1 {
    border: 0;
}
[dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

It does not have an outline.

However, if give it a class `b2` and do:

```
.b2 {
  border: 0;
}
.b2.outline {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

It does have an outline!

Codepen to see for yourselves: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRMBdZ

Why does that happen?

Comment: Specificity:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity

Comment: Remove the space before `.b1` and the behavior is the same.

Comment: This happens because of your selector. With `[dir="ltr"]` just before `.b1` it has a higher priority than `.b2`. So the style in `button.outline` has also higher priority than `.b2` and it overrides `border: 0;`.

Comment: @Turnip I understand specificity. It however does not seem to be the problem as "[dir=ltr] .b1.outline" > "[dir=ltr] .b1" >

Comment: It is absolutely the problem. `button.outline` is more specific than `.b2` so you never remove the border colour.

Comment: `border-width: 1px;` alone will not set a border. You are removing the colour and border style in `[dir="ltr"] .b1`

Comment: @Amit, there's really nothing wrong with your CSS specificty. `[dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {}` will always be stronger than `[dir='ltr'] .b1{}`. You just need to make sure all required properties of border are set for it to display. Cool question and interesting edge case, btw. Cheers!

Comment: "Codepen to see for yourselves" — Provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with specifity and the use of `border: 0;`. The specificity of the two sets of selectors applies `border: 0;` in a different order than one another. `border` is a shorthand property used to apply `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`. Applying `0` or `none` will remove the styles for all of those properties.

In your CodePen you have `button.outline` which is playing a role in the visibility of the button's border.

Your first set is applied in this order:

1. `button.outline` - `border-style` and `border-color` properties applied
2. `[dir="ltr"] .b1` - border properties removed with `border: 0;`
3. `[dir="ltr"] .b1.ouline` - `border-width` applied, no color or style

Border is not visible even though there is a width because the rest of the border properties do not have values that would make it visible, like color and style.

---

Your second set is applied in this order:

1. `.b2` - border properties removed with `border: 0;`
2. `button.outline` - `border-style` and `border-color` properties applied
3. `.b2.ouline` - `border-width` applied

Border is visible because we have border properties that make it visible, i.e. width, color, style.

Comment: You really did not provide a proper answer to the question. The question was: why isn't [`dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {}` applying over `[dir="ltr"] .b1 {}`. And the answer is: it is applying for `border-width` correctly. However, the `border-style` remains set to `initial` by `border:0;` property. Your answer doesn't even touch the core of the problem.

Comment: It's still a specificity issue when it comes to the specificity of `border: 0;` between the `.b1` and .`b2` selectors. Though I agree the answer should go into more detail in respect to the `border` property. I'll refine it.

Comment: I didn't quite welcome the *"it's still a specificity issue"* reply from you, as well as your initial *"You should brush up on CSS specificity"* opener, when that was not really the issue. I usually appreciate your answers/presence on [so]. I apologize for being aggressive.

Answer (score 3):

It's because

```
border:0;
```

... translates to:

```css
border-top-color: initial;
border-top-style: initial;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-color: initial;
border-right-style: initial;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-color: initial;
border-bottom-style: initial;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: initial;
border-left-style: initial;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
```

This means the `border-style` property is set to `initial`, which defaults it to `none`. The width applies, but the style is `initial` = `none`. You need to set it any render-able value so it applies a visible border:

```css
[dir="ltr"] .b1 {
  border: 0;
}

[dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: (Not OP btw.) Yep.  `[dir="ltr"] .b1.outline` *is* higher cascade value than `[dir="ltr"] .b1`, but it doesn't matter because `border-style` has been overridden by the `border` shorthand.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's exactly what I said. `border-style` is set to `initial`, which is `none`, by `border: 0;`. What exactly is not clear?

Comment: Not sure, man.  I think this is the right answer.  Not sure why it got a downvote.

Comment: I re-worded it so it's clearer. But it was correct in the first explanation. Just not so clear and bold. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you add the [dir="ltr"], it changes the order in which rules are processed.

For Button 1 (no outline):

```
[dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {
    border-width: 1px;
}

[dir="ltr"] .b1 {
    border: 0;
}

button.outline {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #387ef5;
    color: #387ef5;
    background-color: transparent;
}

button {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}
```

And for Button 2 (outline):

```
.b2.outline {
    border-width: 1px;
} 

button.outline {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #387ef5;
    color: #387ef5;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.b2 {
    border: 0;
}

button {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}
```

Notice how `button.outline` is the 3rd rule on Button 1 and the 2nd rule on Button 2 since the specificity changed.

Answer (score 0):

Take in count the rules of CSS. If you have more levels of nesting, this will be the priority. In your case, `.b2` is the basic level, so when you set `button.outline` this will be more important than `.b2` rule, for that reason all `.b2` elements will have the outline. If you want to rewritte the rules, you have to call `button.b2.outline` instead only `.b2`

```
    /* BASE CLASSES */
    button {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    .outline { /* Only use one level */
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #387ef5;
        color: #387ef5;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    /* B1 + DIRECTION */
    [dir="ltr"] .b1 {
        border: 0;
    }
    [dir="ltr"] .b1.outline {
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    /* B2 NO DIRECTION */
    button.b2 { /* Be more specific to replace previous rule */
      border: 0;
    }
    button.b2.outline {
      border-width: 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the styles with the `[dir="ltr"]` selector have higher precedence.

When you set:

```
[dir="ltr"] .b1 {border: 0}
```

You make all border-specific declarations in `button.outline {...}` obsolete. Therefore you have a `border-width`, but neither `border-style` nor `border-color` which are just as well necessary.