# :valid pseudoclass has greater priority than a custom class defined later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

CSS styles defined later should have greater priority (if the selectors are have the same strength).
For instance:

```css
/* Let's make it red */
h1 {
  color: red;
}

/* Well... actually blue */
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I was expecting the same thing to happen for `input:valid` and `input:invalid`, but it seems like `input:valid` *is stronger* than `input.is-valid` (a custom class defined *later*).

Here is an example:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
 $("input").addClass("is-invalid")
})
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.is-invalid {
  /* Without adding !important, this isn't applied */
  border: 2px solid orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required>
<button>Run custom validation and declare it .is-invalid</button>
```

So, if we do not add `!important` to the `.is-invalid` class, `input:valid` and `input:invalid` will still have greater priority.

How should I address this? Is it a browser bug/feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Understanding the selector's priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity)

Comment: as @JonathanBrooks says it's because of specificity. if you declare rule as input.is-invalid it would override input:invalid/input:valid rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the priority of the selectors: `.is-invalid` will be more important than `input:valid`.