# Override !important In WordPress Parent Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, child-theming

I have the following CSS code in a custom.css style sheet which is part of the Main theme

```
.thm-unit-test h3 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
}
```

I have added the following code to my child theme CSS

```
.thm-unit-test h3 {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

But it is not not working. With this in mind how do I override the **!important** in the main custom.css. Because if I can override it than the code in my child theme can take effect

Comment: make sure your code is placed after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Body tag in front of it... be more specific:

```
body .thm-unit-test h3 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
}
```

Or other parent elements...

Take some time to understand CSS Selector Priority:

[Understanding CSS selector priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity)

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than
> a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an
> element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules.
>
> These rules have no
> selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.) count the number of ID
> attributes in the selector (= b) count the number of other attributes
> and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c) count the number of element
> names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d) The specificity is
> based only on the form of the selector.
>
> the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0,
> c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the
> source document's DTD. Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a
> number system with a large base) gives the specificity.
>
> In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector
> (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source
> document's DTD.
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the > specificity.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

I'd use an ID in front of it tbf.

Comment: That's no problem at all, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

It should work, make sure that the call for the css of the main theme is above your custom css in the HTML

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themeCss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCustomCss.css">
</head>
```

Let me know if that help you!

Comment: This is a WordPress Theme. I am trying to override the css in the main style sheet, with one created in the child theme

Comment: add your cusom child stylhesheet after the main stylesheet; ie, use the priority value, like: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_child_stylesheet', X );