# why is my background-color is not working for a specific class selector?

Tags: css, background-color

I am new to HTML, CSS. Recently I was learning CSS grid property. I created some boxes with a div container and some items on it with a class selector. But I wanted to give style to a specific item with the class `taco`.

Though I defined background-color in `.container` div", but I can't change the `background-color` in the specific item called `taco`. I tried adding `background-color` by inline CSS in the div with class name `taco`.

In this case the `background-color` works but when I try to do the same thing in style.css file the `background-color` doesn't work for that specific item "taco". What I am missing here?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: url(images/topography.svg), linear-gradient(110deg, #f93d66, #6d47d9);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container div {
  background-color: rgb(182, 182, 58);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.taco {
  grid-column: 1/ -2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*background-color: #ffffff; doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="taco">&#127790;</div>
  <!--style="background-color: #ffffff;" works-->
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
  <div class="item item11">11</div>
  <div class="item item12">12</div>
  <div class="item item13">13</div>
  <div class="item item14">14</div>
  <div class="item item15">15</div>
  <div class="item item16">16</div>
  <div class="item item17">17</div>
  <div class="item item18">18</div>
  <div class="item item19">19</div>
  <div class="item item20">20</div>
  <div class="item item21">21</div>
  <div class="item item22">22</div>
  <div class="item item23">23</div>
  <div class="item item24">24</div>
  <div class="item item25">25</div>
  <div class="item item26">26</div>
  <div class="item item27">27</div>
  <div class="item item28">28</div>
  <div class="item item29">29</div>
  <div class="item item30">30</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a heads up, I answered your specific question to show you where the error was, I do recommend that you read the duplicate and even the MDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are running into a specificity problem:

`.container div` is more specific than `.taco`. If you add `div.taco` as the selector, you'll get a CSS selector that is more specific.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: url(images/topography.svg), linear-gradient(110deg, #f93d66, #6d47d9);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container div {
  background-color: rgb(182, 182, 58);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

div.taco {
  grid-column: 1/ -2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*background-color: #ffffff; doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="taco">&#127790;</div>
  <!--style="background-color: #ffffff;" works-->
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
  <div class="item item11">11</div>
  <div class="item item12">12</div>
  <div class="item item13">13</div>
  <div class="item item14">14</div>
  <div class="item item15">15</div>
  <div class="item item16">16</div>
  <div class="item item17">17</div>
  <div class="item item18">18</div>
  <div class="item item19">19</div>
  <div class="item item20">20</div>
  <div class="item item21">21</div>
  <div class="item item22">22</div>
  <div class="item item23">23</div>
  <div class="item item24">24</div>
  <div class="item item25">25</div>
  <div class="item item26">26</div>
  <div class="item item27">27</div>
  <div class="item item28">28</div>
  <div class="item item29">29</div>
  <div class="item item30">30</div>
</div>
```

Here is some documentation about specificity:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

And some more from Stack Overflow:
[Understanding CSS selector priority / specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity)