# Website is not scrolling horizontally on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following website [website](http://www.khudagenealogicalservices.com). Problem is when opened in a mobile browser the content doesn't scroll horizontally. I have added `overflow:scroll;` to the body in the default.css but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Please help.

Comment: Are you using vanilla CSS or a library/framework? Have you tried to be [more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4072365/7665043) with the CSS selector? How about playing with it in dev tools?

Comment: @l3l_aze, he is neither using a library or a framework.

Comment: Always submit the related code when asking questions about bugs

Comment: I think ykd's answer is right but do the blue background supposedly react that way after resizing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained as external links can change so when you fix your website then the problem cannot be seen anymore and that makes the question invalid and unhelpful to other users.

Comment: first the sity is poorle optimized for mobile use. it has a media query but only to remove the banner. There elements with a min-width of 1200px. Fixed pixel values espacially that high work poorly with mobile use. Also you used overflow:hidden which will remove the scroll ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `overflow:hidden` on **default.css line: 363** and try again.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try using width property on header-wrapper and wrapper divs. This allowed me to scroll horizontally.