# How to set all element have 0 padding 0 margin on global styling

Tags: css

I am working using nextjs, typescript, and scss. on global.scss there is *(asterisk selector) to set padding and margin to be zero(0) , but its not working

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```js
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Share any screenshot ?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/gXYsn0cJ

Comment: has any of the answers solves the issue?

Comment: using !important solves the issue, but why it should using !important?

Comment: as its name suggests, it adds more importance to that property., but I keep it as last option. Try my answer also whether it works?

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 not works, but if using !important its work

Comment: Dont use `!important` for this. Why? [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css). Use proper cascading instead. `*` is a very weak selector, it gets overwritten by literally _anything_ else like `h1`, `.foo` or any other selector that has a specitivity of 1 or more. What is specitivity? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity).

Comment: add your global.scss after all the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
    * {
         box-sizing: border-box !important;
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important;
      }
```

Comment: Dont use `!important` for this. Why? [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css). Use proper cascading instead.

Comment: i just gave an answer specific to the question. question is not about whether its a good practice or not. @FabianS.

Comment: I know, i did not say your answer doesnt match the question cause _it does_. I just wanted to point out, that using `!important` this way is bad practise and can lead to huge problems later on. Should have said "like this" instead of "for this" that would have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This will only reset the `padding` and `margin` on the `body` tag. [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) and [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) are not inherited in css so this will only affect the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the selector's [specitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity) of `*` is less than `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`.

That means the `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` selectors values will overwrite the values defined in `*`.

Yes, you could use `!important` to get around this by completely overruling any specitivity but that breaks the whole cascading feature (aka specitivity) of css and will haunt you at night.
Why? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css).

The proper solution on your issue would be to properly overwrite the margin on the `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` selector by yourself in the cases you need it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  /* this will overwrite the margin:0 and set the color to red from the * selector */
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.mycontentwrapper h1 {
  /* this will overwrite the margin:10px from the h1,h2 selector */
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mycontentwrapper h2 {
  /* this will overwrite the margin and color from the h1,h2 selector */
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontentwrapper">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <h2>Test 2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box ;
  padding: 0px ;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This will only reset the `padding` and `margin` on the `html` tag. [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) and [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) are not inherited in css so this will only affect the `html` tag.