# Material UI CSS overriding makeStyles CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating classes using makeStyles and useClasses. But in most of the cases, MUI CSS is getting applied and my classes are only getting applied by using '!important'. Is there a way to override MUI styles without '!important'. While using important, some by default
MUI CSS is failing. Also from the same code logo is working properly without even using !important. [This shows MUI CSS overriding makeStyles CSS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6kOn.jpg)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.svg";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    toolbarMargin: {
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        marginBottom: "3em",
    },
    logo: {
        height: "8em",
    },
    tabContainer: {
        marginLeft: "auto",
    },
    tab: {
        ...theme.typography.tab,
        minWidth: 10,
        marginLeft: "25px !important",
    },
    button: {
        ...theme.typography.estimate,
        borderRadius: "50px !important",
        marginLeft: "50px !important",
        marginRight: "25px !important",
        height: "45px !important",
    },
    logoContainer: {
        padding: "0px !important",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
    },
}));


export default function Header(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ElevationScroll>
                <AppBar position='fixed'>
                    <Toolbar disableGutters>
                        <Button
                            disableRipple
                            className={classes.logoContainer}
                            component={Link}
                            to='/'
                        >
                            <img src={logo} alt='company Logo' className={classes.logo}></img>
                        </Button>
                        <Tabs
                            className={classes.tabContainer}
                            value={0}
                            textColor='#fff'
                            onChange={handleChnage}
                            indicatorColor='primary'
                        >
                            <Tab
                                className={classes.tab}
                                component={Link}
                                to='/'
                                label='Home'
                            />
                            <Tab
                                className={classes.tab}
                                component={Link}
                                to='/services'
                                label='Services'
                            />
                        </Tabs>
                        <Button
                            variant='contained'
                            className={classes.button}
                            color='secondary'
                        >
                            Free Estimate
                        </Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </ElevationScroll>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your problem is the selectors [specitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity). As both selectors are equally specific, the one that gets defined later on will overwrite the first one. By using `!important` youre breaking specitivity. I dont know `makeCss` well, but the solution would be increasing the specitivity of the selector created by `makeCss`. This will make it overwrite your MUI styles by specitivity and youll be able to drop all `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all these styles in a CSS file and import that file inside last of your html file.

Or you can use !important tag on every style that has been overridden:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    toolbarMargin: {
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        marginBottom: "3em" !important,
    },
    logo: {
        height: "8em" !important,
    },
    tabContainer: {
        marginLeft: "auto",
    },
    tab: {
        ...theme.typography.tab,
        minWidth: 10px !important,
        marginLeft: "25px !important",
    },
    button: {
        ...theme.typography.estimate,
        borderRadius: "50px !important",
        marginLeft: "50px !important",
        marginRight: "25px !important",
        height: "45px !important",
    },
    logoContainer: {
        padding: "0px !important",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
    },
}));
```

Comment: Question explicitly asks about not using `!important` - _"Is there a way to override MUI styles without '!important'"_

Comment: Use CSS modules or import CSS file end of you html file

Comment: Material UI is so terrible... how can using !importants be acceptable