# Change the text size of a select SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, css, select, sapui5, font-size

I have the following select, and I want to change its size, both the size of the select in general and, more importantly, its text. The text it contains are flags so they are shown as an emoji but as it is inside a text type it should be able to be changed with font-size, but the size remains the same.

```
<Select class="language" autoAdjustWidth="false" id="language" change="onChange">
    <core:ListItem class="icon" key="uk" text="&#127468;&#127463;"/>
    <core:ListItem class="icon" key="es" text="&#x1F1EA;&#x1F1F8;"/>
</Select>
```

This is all I've tried in the css but I don't know which way to go.

```
.language {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
    font-size: 200rem !important;
    border-style: hidden !important;
   /* width: 0.1em !important;*/
   /* width: 65px !important;
    height: 65px;*/
}

.language .sapMBtnText{
    font-size: 20rem !important;
}
.icon .sapMBtnText{
    font-size: 50rem !important;
    width: 60px !important;
}

.icon{
    font-size: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why is every rule in your css marked as `!important`? Are you aware of that that [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) ?

Comment: I think what it does is that it overwrites the sap theme and puts the rule that I put in. @FabianS. Anyway, I have also tried it without `!important` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using proper cascading of your stylesheet (higher [specitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/understanding-css-selector-priority-specificity)) instead of `!important`. It seems something is wrong with the cascade. Can you maybe add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't know how to put a sapui5 MRE code here. Hmm I don't know what could be wrong with the cascade, I thought maybe it's not `sapMBtnText` because I haven't found much reference to it. @FabianS.